# Index a set of files to search their text quickly?

Tags: file-search

I have a unique need: I am frequently searching a large set of text files for a keyword or two.

Right now, I open up [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) and use the "Find in files" feature. It works just fine, but with the amount of files, each search takes a couple minutes to complete.

Is there a good program more suited for this purpose, perhaps that indexes a set of files and then lets you search the set repeatedly and very quickly? It would greatly speed up my workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Agent Ransack**](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) seems like the tool you're looking for.

[image]